# What is the correct way in swift to wrap a segment of a UInt8 array as a String?

Tags: swift, unsafemutablepointer

I have some raw data processing to do in an iPhone app. Strings always come out of an extremely large underlying byte array, so I want to be able to pull strings out of the array without triggering *out of memory* issues.

I can see a `String(bytesNoCopy: ...)` in the documentation, is this what I want, and how exactly is it supposed to be used?

Assuming an array of uint8 called `data` and `index` is a number which shows where the string is inside the array.

```
var myData:[UInt8] = [
    4,                // String 1 length
    65,66,67,68,0,    // String 1 data
    4,                // String 2 length
    69,70,71,71,0     // String 2 data
]

var index = 0
let string1 = readString(&myData, &index)
let string2 = readString(&myData, &index)
print(string1, string2)

// Read a string located at a specific
// position in a byte array, and increment
// the pointer into the array into the next
// position
func readString(_ data:inout [UInt8], _ index:inout Int)  -> String {
    // Read string length out of data array
    let l = Int(readUInt8(&data, &index))

    // Read string out of data array without copy
    let s = String(
        bytesNoCopy: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(data + index), // <-- what goes here??
        length: l,
        encoding: .utf8,
        freeWhenDone: false)
    index = index + l
    if s == nil {
        return ""
    }
    return s!
}

// Read a byte as an integer from a 
// data array, and increment the pointer into
// the data array to the next position.
func readUInt8(_ data:inout [UInt8], _ x:inout Int)  -> UInt8 {
    let v = data[x]
    x = x + 1
    return v
}
```

---

**NOTE:** This question is updated to include sample data, and renamed the variable `x` to `index` to make it clearer that the question was asking how to create a string from a *segment* of a  byte array.

Comment: What does `readUInt8` actually do? The name is pretty useless, and the comment "Read string length out of data array" doesn't actually explain which kind of length this is Is it the count of bytes? Code points? Unicode extended grapheme scalars ("Characters")?

Comment: Swift has a special convenience syntax for passing some types like strings and arrays (of particular types) as pointers, which exists primarily for easier interop with C. Passing `&data` here *does* happen to work, but as far as I recall the validity of that pointer is only valid for the duration of the call, and dangles immediately after.

Comment: @Alexander Yes the backing data is guaranteed to never be deallocated. I too have an aversion to using pointers when they are not necessary, so the caution is wise. But I believe in this case the use of pointers is definitely warranted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do try this -

```
import Foundation

func readString(_ data: inout [UInt8], _ x: inout Int) -> String {
    let l = 4
    var slice: ArraySlice<UInt8> = data[x..<x+l] // No copy, view into existing Array
    x += l
    
    return slice.withUnsafeBytes({ pointer in
        // No copy, just making compiler happy (assumption that it is bound to UInt8 is correct
        if let bytes = pointer.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) {
            return String(
                bytesNoCopy: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: bytes), // No copy
                length: slice.count,
                encoding: .utf8,
                freeWhenDone: false
            ) ?? ""
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    })
}
```

Test

```
var a: [UInt8] = [
    65, 66, 67, 68, 
    69, 70, 71, 72
]
var x = 0

let test1 = readString(&a, &x)
print("test1 : \(test1)")
// test1 : ABCD

let test2 = readString(&a, &x)
print("test2 : \(test2)")
// test2 : EFGH
```

Comment: That is some seriously awesome swift ninja fu right there. Amazing! Im only just now moving from objective-c to swift so there is a bit of a steep learning curve for me here, so I appreciate your responses.

Comment: Just be really careful not to deallocate your backing array too early. Honestly, this is all really fragile, and ripe for accidental foot-gunning. Make sure there really is no other way to use regular "independent" strings.